# Auto-correct line lengths in a library

Tags: ruby, syntax, rubocop

I am working on a huge project and we have decided to make all code conform to 80 characters per line. It is a ruby based project with wrappers for C. For Ruby, I decided to use Rubocop and with the command:

```
rubocop --only LineLength
```

I got 1,714 errors, where length of the line was greater than 80 characters. Aside from that, there were many other errors detected by Rubocop which I want to ignore for now.

I am looking for the easiest way to auto-correct all the line length violations *only*, to satisfy the 80 character limit both in C and Ruby.

Comment: I suggest you first scan the code to determine the most common reasons that lines exceed 80 characters. I would not be surprised if a main culprit is long variable and method names. If so, you might be able reduce the number of "long" lines (> 80 chars) considerably by merely shortening those strings. "Merely" is perhaps not the right word, since that is no simple task. You need to avoid shortening names of Ruby's built-in methods, of course, as well as some quoted strings. (I say "some" because you might define a method `doit` and then find it referenced as a string: `A.send("doit")`.)...

Comment: ...You might start by scannin your code for strings which you'd put in an array `arr`, then `arr.uniq!.sort!`. Next go though and remove strings that obviously cannot be shortened. Then create a hash that maps each string to itself, then manually modify each value to something shorter but still meaningful. After confirming there are no duplicate values in the hash, use the hash to shorten strings in the code...

Comment: ...In addition, there are places where you can safely break lines, such as after vertical pipes surrounding block variables, commas that are not within quoted strings, and so on. You might use regular expressions for that. Best of luck! After you are finished, please report back with an edit that explains what you did and any pitfalls you encountered. It would be especially interesting if you report percentage reductions in long lines you achieved by each technique you use. If you do that, please let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't change line length automatically.

Linelength is a *metric*, not a *style*. Styles can often be exchanged, like double vs. single quotes, using hashrockets vs. the new hash syntax introduced in ruby 2 etc. Choosing a style is usually a matter of taste and has few (if any) impact on the program itself. That's why there are auto corrections for styles: Changing them does not change semantics.

Metrics include linelength, [classlength](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_metrics/#metricsclasslength) and [ABC-Size](https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_metrics/#metricsabcsize), among others. Checking metrics using static code analysis is something completely different than checking styles. Setting a maximum to linelength for instance is not a matter of taste, you'd rather use it to enforce a certain style of programming. A programmer would have to avoid long variable names and deep nesting to keep the linelength under the limit.

Metrics can also indicate problems in the code. For example, too high ABC-size indicates a method might be doing too much.

Aside from that, it would be very difficult, if not impossible, to shorten all lines of code automatically, since ruby is a very complex language.

Instead of reducing linelength automatically, here's some alternatives:

- see if you can reduce the number of violations by enabling the AllowHeredoc and AllowURI options. Read about them here https://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cops_metrics/#metricslinelength.
- run `rubocop --only LineLength --auto-gen-config` and use rubocops configuration to stop checking linelength.
- ask yourself: What value do I gain by reducing linelength?
- don't think of too long lines as style violation, but rather as a possible indicator of an underlying problem. Try to find that problem, and solve it.

Comment: To me it seems like formulaic wrapping of lines would make them more consistent and save work. The idea that a long line indicates some larger deep problem means that we should have a check that checks line complexity. Often, though this is not the case. And line length is a potential problem in at least an order of magnitude more places than lines per method or lines per file. And to me, heredocs are much worse than long lines.